# Stopwatch timer not updated while AndroidDriver is waiting

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a specific case in which I have to pause my driver using a method found somewhere here on s/o for a minute in order to achieve a valid booking time(>60s) which looks like this:

```
return waitf.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            WebElement timer = null;
            try {
                timer = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Utils.STOPWATCH_TIMER));
                String timerTextString = timer.getText(); // so question
                LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse(timerTextString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss"));
                if (localTime.isAfter(LocalTime.of(0, 1, 5))) {
                    return true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now, the thing is that the variable timerTextString doesn't update, because when I debugged the value(0:00:00) it didn't change the whole time. My understanding of it was that the driver should poll and check every xx miliseconds and update the value. On the web version of my application it worked but on the mobile app I have this presented situation. I also tried using implicit wait but it didn't help me.